# How can I store the users' data properly?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, key

I am restoring data for users' in a nested dictionary as follows:

```
   user_dict = {user_name:{product:amount, product:amount}}
```

So, user_name is the user's user_name. The product is the what the user put in the basket(e.g. orange juice), and the amount is the amount of a specific product. So, for instance:

```
user_dict = {"sara" : {"orange juice": 2, "apple juice" : 4}, "ali": {"banana":3}}
```

what I want to do is that when a user buys some stuff and put them in the (user_dict) then logs out, when the same user logs in again, I want to get the user's basket as follows: let's say sara logged in and put some stuff in her basket(user_dict) then logged out, when sara logs in again, I want to make get sara's information from the (user_dict) in a new dictionary(called basket) like this:

```
basket = {"orange juice": 2, "apple juice" : 4}
```

Also, I want to make the basket empty if the user (user_name) who logged in does not have anything in the basket. So, I want to make users' things do not interfere and I do not want to lose any information. I have almost finished my project but this is what I am stuck at, so help me guys, please.

Here are my lines of code for this task:(but the code does not work as I want)

```
for key in user_dict.keys():
    if user_name == key:
        key_sto = " "
        nested_dict = user_dict[user_name]
        val = a.values()
        val_in_nested = val[0]
        key_in_nested = key_sto.join(a)
        basket[key_in_nested] = val_in_nested
    elif user_name != key :
        basket = {}
```

Comment: What you want is some kind of session management. Most common frameworks (django, flask) have this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem, so here is the code.

```
for key, amount in user_dict.items():
    if key == user_name:
        basket = amount

if user_name not in user_dict.keys():
    basket = {}
```